# How to add menu button to Tab Bar Controller

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, navigation-drawer

Hello all I am making an app that uses a tab bar controller with three tabs as well as a slide out navigation drawer. and my question is how do I put a bar button item in the top  left hand corner. It doesn't show when I run my app but it shows in a regular view controller. here is the code I have.

```
#import "FirstViewController.h"
#import "SWRevealViewController.h"

@interface FirstViewController ()

@end

@implementation FirstViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [[UITabBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];


    [self.tabBarController setTitle:@"News"];

    // Change button color
    _sidebarButton.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.1f alpha:0.9f];

    // Set the side bar button action. When it's tapped, it'll show up the sidebar.
    _sidebarButton.target = self.revealViewController;
    _sidebarButton.action = @selector(revealToggle:);

    // Set the gesture
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:self.revealViewController.panGestureRecognizer];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

[image: just so you can see what im on about (firstview)]

Comment: Add a navigation bar.

Comment: @Vineesh TP How do I add a navigation bar to my firstView Controller which is a tab bar without it being behind the top bar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you seem to be using storyboard, my recommendation is to find the `Bar Button Item` in the  `Object Library` and drag it into the top left hand corner of your FirstViewController (and any other controller that you want the button in). This will replace the original back button created by the Navigation Controller with your own button. In the button's Attribute Inspector you can give it an image, and connect it to your code by control+dragging to your `FirstViewController.h` file.

Comment: Thats what I've currently been doing, but when I run the app the button doesnt show and there is no feedback. Also the slide gesture works

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a @property for your button

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.sidebarButton;
```

Also, is this the best place to customize your TabBar?

Comment: thanks for the response, yes i do have the property set in the .h file as you assumed,but it still doesn't work, the code has no errors but there still is no button.

Comment: Could you explain why you have the Reveal View Controller connected as you do through a Navigation Controller ahead of the Tab Bar Controller?